# Computer programming

Tags: processor, machine-code

i have a question concerning computer programming. Let's say i have only one computer with no OS running. And would like to start to "develop" an OS. basically what i have is a blank sheet an a pen to do so. an a couple of electronic devices. how do i put my instruction into that computer?
because today we use interpreter of compiler that "turn" programming language into what they call "machine code". But my question could be how to generate machine code from nowhere.
Thank you for your replies, a link to learn how to do that will be must welcome.

Comment: You typically use another computer, *with* an operating system, and use *cross-compiling* to compile for the target. I recommend you read the tutorials on the [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page).

Comment: hello @JoachimPileborg i get that, but how was the first computer was used then? how was the first compiler was then develop. this what i'm actually looking for

Comment: Strictly speaking, you just need to be able to download your program into some sort of memory on the machine, then tell the CPU to start working from that memory location and there you have it. How to do that without using software, is however not an on-topic question for SO.

Comment: The first computers didn't have any operating system. And when operating systems (or their precursors) were developed there were other computers and other systems (punch-cards etc.) to use.

Comment: On early machines you entered the binary code for your program directly on the system console like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7090#/media/File:IBM_7094_console2.agr.JPG). You had to work out the binary yourself.

Comment: @Lundin ok. but what is the "program" then? "is however not an on-topic question for SO" - what should be the topic then? I'm looking up for it for years now. Seems like it is the heart of money making :). See i work in computer and have a basic knnowledge of all this cross compiling things, but i am missing a piece there.

Comment: @greg-449 thank you, there we go it is a start of what i am actually looking for. show they used some kind of alternator to send electronic sequence?

Comment: @FranckNgako The program is as expected, just a raw binary, with numbers corresponding to the instruction set of the CPU. It is perfectly possible to write any computer program just as a collection of ones and zeroes. Which in turn can be abstracted into hexadecimal for better readability. Which in turn can be abstracted into assembler instructions. An assembler instruction is nothing but a textual label for a numeric instruction (op code).

Comment: @lundin thank you. all your explanation are very clear. let say now i want to bypass the assembler to interact with my computer. because assembly seems to be a software component too that translate text to opcode. so what i want to know is how can i generate opcode out of nowhere? seems like it is impossible those days

Comment: @FranckNgako You open the CPU manual and read which op code every instruction has. But since all CPU manuals include the assembler instructions, you'd have to look at an op code table or [op code map](http://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/tech/HC908/opcode_map.gif), to see which instruction that corresponds to which op code. All very tedious work, there's a reason why assembler was invented :)

Comment: @Lundin thank you for your time :).  thank to everybody too. all info provided were from high quality. the answer i am looking for seems to resid into perforated card and is more into hardware than into software.

Answer (score 3):

The first computers where programmed making the "machine code" directly. Just punching one's an zeros into cards (well, in fact they punched octal digits).

This was done that way until somebody thought it would be a nice idea to have an assembler which translated the machine code instructions into that ones and zeros.

After that, another guy thought that it can be very nice idea to have a programming language, who will translate "top level" instructions to machine code.

And after that, or probably at the same time, some "internal procedures" where created to ease the programming: to open a file, to close a file the only thing you have to do is to call an internal subroutine in the machine instead of programming all the open file and close file subroutines by yourself: the seed for the operating systems was planted.

The *cross compiling* issue that is commented here is the way to create an operating system for a new computer nowadays: you use a working computer as a "lever" to create an operating system for a new computer.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how far back you want to go.  the earliest ones "programming" was moving wires from one essentially analog alu to another.
The woman/women programming at this point were called computers and used use pencil and paper.

later you use a pencil and paper and the datasheet/documentation for the instruction set.  assemble by hand basically, there are no compilers or even the concept of a programming language at this point, this has to evolve still.  you wrote down the ones and zeros in whatever form you preferred (binary or octal).

one way to enter code at this point is with switches.  certainly computers predated it but look for a picture of the front panel of a pdp8 or the altair, etc.  you set the switches for the data value and address, and you manually strobe a write.  you load the bootstrap in this way and/or the whole program. set the start address and switch to run mode.

over time they developed card and tape readers for which you loaded the bootstrap in by hand (switches) then you could use a reader to load larger programs easier.  cards could be punched on a typewriter type thing, literally a keyboard but instead of striking through a ribbon onto paper, it cut slots in a card.

oses and programming languages started to evolve at this point.  until you bootstrapped your compiler you had to write the first compiler for a new language in some other language (no different than today).  so the first assembler had to be in machine code, then from assembler you could create some other language and so on.

If you wanted to repeat something like this today you would have to build a computer with some sort of manual input.  you could certainly but you would have to design it that way, like then you need the debouncing out but you could for example have a processor with an external flash, be it parallel or serial, mux the lines to the switches (a switch controls the mux) and either address/data/write your program, or for fun could use a spi flash and serially load the program into the flash.  much better to just use one of the pdp or altair, etc online simulators to get a feel for the experience.

there is no magic here, there is no chicken and egg problem at all.  humans had to do it by hand before the computer could do it.  a smaller/simpler program had to generate more complicated programs, and so on.   this long, slow, evolution is well documented all over the internet and in books in libraries everywhere.

Comment: thank you @dwelch. Could you provide me some key words in order to fin that over the internet or some book references that coud help. Thank you for your reply again. Regards

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800 that took a few seconds to search for.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping  and so on.  numerous books on the topic, basically anything to do with computer history, that is old enough will touch on the transition from having to use the switches to load the card/tape loader to the operating system or programs.  I dont think the term bare metal was used back then as everything was bare metal.

Comment: you can also look at the most recent languages, brand new ones, that require a current (different) language for the first compiler before they can re-write the compiler in that language.    eventually like current languages relying on some other computer to cross compile to bring up the nth computer. (linux from scratch, how do you compile an existing os from scratch?  using another os or installation)

Answer (score 0):

Computers are based on a physical processor which was designed to accept instructions (eg. in assembly code) that only allowed primitive instructions like shift, move, copy, add.  This processor decided how it spoke (eg. how big were the words (8-bit) and and other specs (speed/standards etc). Using some type of storage, we could store the instructions (punch cards, disk) and execute huge streams of these instructions.

If instructions were repeated over and over, you could move to an address and execute what was at that location and create loops and other constructs (branches, context switches, recursion).

Since you would have peripherals, you would have some kind of way to interface with it (draw, print dots), and you could create routines to build up on that to build letters, fonts, boxes, lines.  Then you could run a subroutine to print the letter 'a' on screen..

An OS is basically a high-level implementation of all those lower level instructions.  It is really a collection of all the instructions to interface with different areas (i/o, computations etc).  Unix is a perfect example of different folks working on different areas and plugging them all into a single OS.